# Linear map $f(x^n)=nf(x)$.

Tags: recurrence-relations

I want to find a linear map $f$ with the property $f(x^n)=nf(x)$.

Suppose we have the recurrence $x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}=x_{n+1}$ with $x_1=a$. If such a map exists then $0=f(x_{n+1})$. So $f$ attains roots at $x_2,x_3,....$.

Does $\{x_2,x_3,....\}$ account for all real numbers if we are allowed to vary $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: By linear function, do you mean $f(x) = ax + b$?

Comment: No $f(c_1x+c_2y)=c_1f(x)+c_2(y)$ @Ennar

Comment: There is no way $\{x_2,x_3,\ldots\}$ contains all real numbers since $\{x_2,x_3,\ldots\}$ is a countable set.

Comment: In any case, fix $n$. If $f\neq 0$, you get a polynomial of degree $n$, which can't have more than $n$ roots, contradiction.

Comment: don't call it a linear map , by doing so you're saying that you can speak about the power of a vector which is immpossible , just call it a morphisme insteas of a linear map

Comment: @Seginus, no, that is untrue, you can take powers of vectors in any algebra over a field.

Comment: I've never heard about that , what your definition of a power of a vector ?

Comment: @Seginus, please see  [Algebra over a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field). Elementary examples are $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$, matrix algebras $M_n(k)$, polynomial algebras $k[X]$, etc., all of which are vector spaces by definition, and since there is multiplication in algebras, there are powers as well, assuming (power) associativity.

Comment: I didn't find anything that shows what you say , I don't think you get the definitions

Comment: @Seginus, I've just written you many examples, I'm not sure what you don't understand about them.

Comment: when we're talking about power of an element this element isn't seen as a vector it is seen as an element over a ring the example you just gave right now are taken from an algebra and not in a vector space , so your definitions aren't correct

Comment: @Seginus, algebra (over a field) = vector space + ring by definition, if I take power inside algebra, I'm taking a power of a vector, not much more to say about it. Contemplate on it.

Comment: why you don't get it , taking a vector space which is not an algebra you can't talk about the power of the vectors , that's it , as easy as that

Comment: @Seginus, I will repeat my comment: "Seginus, no, that is untrue, you can take powers of vectors in any algebra over a field." This effectively makes your statement "[... ] you're saying that you can speak about the power of a vector which is immpossible" invalid. Especially since in this case we are talking about real numbers, a well known _algebra_.

Comment: OUUUUUUUUUUUPS i'm so sorry i'm stupid

Comment: @Seginus, it's fine as long as we reached an agreement. Take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0\neq 0$ be a number so that $f(x_0)=0$. Then for any $c\in \Bbb R$, we have $f(cx_0)=cf(x_0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

we have $f(1^n)=nf(1)$ for all positive $n$, so $f(1)=0$. We also have $0=f((-1)^2)=2f(-1)$ and so $f(-1)=0$.

Since the function is linear and has two roots we have $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.